# Adobe AIR application GUI not working on Mac OS

Tags: macos, air, adobe, window

We have an Adobe AIR app, which was created by a 3rd party contractor, that we have been using successfully on Windows.  The application runs full screen automatically and, for the most part, primarily is chrome for displaying some web pages.

On windows, it works perfectly.  Only now, 9 months after development, has someone asked to try to run it on a Mac.  We figured it would work since AIR is cross platform.  It installs just fine (latest AIR SDK on OSX Lion).  When we run the app, it launches but only shows the name of the app next to the Apple symbol in the upper left.  No window or other chrome appears on the screen.  I can Quit the app from the menu, but not much else.

Any thoughts as to why it's behaving this way on the Mac and not Windows?  We do not have access to the original developer, and I am not a Flash/Flex person, but I do have the source and a copy of Flash Builder 4, so I could make basic tweaks.  Any pointers would be very appreciated.

Comment: +1 here.  
We have a very similar problem. Ours is even more annoying, because the application used to run just fine on AIR 2.7.1 on Mac. Suddenly, upon a fresh reinstall, it stopped working and showed exactly the same behaviour you are describing. We are almost sure nothing relevant has changed (OS version, AIR runtime, DMG installer). But obviously something must be different, or we could not explain the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call maximize() after creation complete? I had the same problem (main window not showing up on Mac OS, everything is fine on Windows). Hope this helps.